# How to compute the velocity & distance from Tri-Axial Accelerometer Data?

Tags: math, accelerometer, physics

I'm having sample data of tri-axial accelerometer as listed below:

```
Timestamp, AcceX, AcceY, AcceZ
0.0, -0.96, -0.69, -1.24
0.1, ............
```

I want to determine velocity and distance traveled by the object with accelerometer.

Comment: Wouldn't first order differnce equations be a good first approximation?  v(i+1) = v(i) + a(i)*dt, u(i+1) = u(i) + v(i)*dt

Comment: Will require a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) if any type of precision is needed.

Comment: @Felix: Kalman filters are sometimes used in dead reckoning, particularly when folding in other known factors such as a GPS signals, but to say "will require" is far from the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining the velocity and position from an accelerometer is much harder than it might at first seem.

Depending on your specific needs, there might be a way to form an estimate that would work, but it is generally a very inaccurate approach, and almost worthless given what's usually available on a phone.  With specialized equipment one can do much better.

**First problem:** gravity will be recorded as an acceleration and it's hard to remove (so you at least need a gyro too).

**Second problem:** to get distance and velocity you need to integrate your acceleration so small errors will accumulate.

To find out more, search for "dead reckoning".  See, for example, [the first google hit i got](http://www.chrobotics.com/library/accel-position-velocity), which seems to explain the issues well enough.